# Где искать информацию по архитектуре продакшен решений (в частности Django, flask)?

Tags: python, django, flask, highload

Все курсы\книги которые встречаю описывают базовые моменты и базовые настройки системы.
Меня интересует как это работает реально в продакшене и как грамотно продумать такую архитектуру.
Например как выполняется заливка нового релиза если в базе 24\7 работаю пользователи?
Как настраивается 2 одновременно запущенных приложения django для балансировки?
Как правильно организовать высоконагруженную систему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что дальше больше нужен опыт который описать сложнее и который чаще не относится к конкретной технологии. К примеру:

> Например как выполняется заливка нового релиза если в базе 24\7
> работаю пользователи?

прекрасный вопрос, и решается он не в контексте Django. Например это уже прыжок в сторону docker swarm. Ну или есть вот доклад от разработчика VK как это делают они https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3U8ud34FUs

> Как настраивается 2 одновременно запущенных приложения django для балансировки?

Это можно сделать опять же настроив swarm или просто запустив 2 инстанса джанги на разных серверах (например) и настроив HAProxy на балансировку между ними. есть клевый курс по highload https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBmRmUvFrOg там об этом говорится.
И про балансировку https://youtu.be/7HTYrx3neJk

> Как правильно организовать высоконагруженную систему?

Это очень общий вопрос. Рекомендую посмотреть курс с 1-го видео по 7-е (последнее). Там это разибрается. Все зависит не от приложений, а больше от данных с которыми нужно работать.

Ну и в целом все это очень общие вопросы на которые нельзя дать четкий ответ. Уметь инструмент это одно. А тут нужно уметь готовить концепции. И тогда будет не важно (грубо говоря) какой будет инструмент.

Comment: спасибо. А в продакшене все на докере крутиться? Само по себе использование докера не замедляет работу и т.п.?

Comment: не не все. я лишь привел это как пример. первое что пришло в голову. докер добавляет много оверхеда на сеть. хотя есть и плюсы. нужно исходить из ситуации, задачи, данных и умений (хотя это в первую очередь). Для спасибо есть кнопка.

Comment: А какие еще варианты, как раз вопрос в том как узнать все или хотя бы основные эти варианты? Или получение информации дальше базовой, это уже скорее какие то сайты\форумы\видео выступления и т.п. ? какой то продвинутой теории как таковой особо не найти?

Comment: так я дал ссылки. одна ведет на канал highload, а вторая ведет на курс по highload. ну и книги, например "Высоконагруженные приложения". гуглить надо) один умный человек сказал: "тот у кого есть интернет, владеет всеми знаниями мира"